# Keep constructor if field annotated

Tags: java, proguard

I have the following class.

```
public class StatusCategory
{
   @JsonProperty("key")
   private final String m_key = null;

   public String getKey()
   {
      return(m_key);
   }
}
```

What is the `-keep` option that will ensure the constructor won't be removed by Proguard?

The following will keep the constructor; however, I don't want to have to specify every single class or package.

```
-keep class oracle.psr.ndr.jira.api.StatusCategory {<init>;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Annotate the constructor with `@JsonCreator` and use `-keepclassmembers` like so:

```
-keepclassmembers public class * {
     @com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator *;
}
```